# como recoger una lista de un properties

Tags: java, lista, archivo-de-propiedades

Necesito recoger los datos de una lista que tengo en un .properties .

ejemplo:

```
numeros = 124234,12342343,12234234,234234,234234,23423
```

y recogerlo en java para poder compararla con el numero que se le ha pedido al usuario para saber si esta premiado. Estado buscando y no encuentro la manera de como crear la lista(si se deberia de recoger como en el ejemplo o de otra manera)  y como recuperarla en java la lista .Se recuperar valores de properties en java pero por mas que intento no consigo recuperar una lista de valores.

Un saludo y gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas!

Para hacerlo como tú lo tienes pensado, metiendo en una sola variable del properties la lista de valores, puedes hacer así:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {

    input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

    String valor = prop.getProperty("numeros");
    String[] valores = valor.split(",");

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

y si lo quieres en una lista, como comenta el compañero:

```
List<String> lista = Arrays.asList(valores);
```

Un saludo

Comment: La clase java.util.ResourceBundle está especialmente diseñada para leer ficheros .properties, lo apropiado es usarla en vez de hacerlo con un InputStream.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo! No la conocía

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información es justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más fácil es que hagas

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("NombreFichero");
String[] valores = bundle.getStringArray("numeros");
```

Si lo que quieres es un `List<String>` y no un Array:

```
List<String> lista = Arrays.asList(valores);
```